# If I delete an image in my application it has to be deleted in the gallery too (using objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have developed a camera application with all basic functionalities. When you take a picture that image will be saved in the newly created folder but if I delete an image in my application its not getting deleted in that folder. I need to delete it permanently using objective C

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: use photos framework

Comment: Check this one (uses Photos framework): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phassetchangerequest

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete something from gallery, you can just use photos from gallery in your app and save to Gallery, but iOS doesn't give such permissions to other app as deleting something from Gallery.(if it is not jailbroken) There is no such functionality in WhatsApp too(or I can't see it).

Comment: You can stop saving images to device photos album in WhatsApp, but its not  possible to delete images once saved in photos album. Same can be implemented in the app. We can't fire a command to delete image in photos album from our app.

Answer (score 0):

> **FOR iOS 8.0+**

You can only delete the `ALAsset` which is created by your app with document API `[ALAsset setImageData:metadata:completionBlock:]`

Saving Image `photo.jpg` to gallery by,

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];
[lib writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage metadata:@{} completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Write image %@ to asset library. (Error %@)", assetURL, error);
}];
```

You can Find this in "Saved Photos" album.
To delete:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
[lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(asset.isEditable) {
            [asset setImageData:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Asset url %@ should be deleted. (Error %@)", assetURL, error);
            }];
        }
    }];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

> `ALAssetLibrary` is Deprecated since iOS 9.0, you can use
>   `PHPhotoLibrary` Instead.

**iOS 9.0+**

```
// Delete asset from library
      [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetArray];

    } completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: I have a question about this is this code deletes image from album only or from photos ? Is deleted photo goes to recently deleted or not ? I am so confused if something like that is real in iOS ...

Comment: I'm getting this error "No visible @interface for phphotolibraray declares the selector 'performchanges"

Answer (score -1):

In collection view didselect method i getting the url of selected image

```
 UIImage *viewImage = _myma; // --- mine was made from drawing context
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        // Request to save the image to camera roll
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);

                NSString *urlString = [assetURL absoluteString];
                selectedurl = urlString;
                //NSLog(@"myurl%@", selectedurl);

            }
```

the in action button used to delete the selected images

```
 NSURL *deleteurl = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedurl];
       NSArray *arrDelete = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:deleteurl , nil];
       NSEnumerator *asset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:arrDelete options:nil];

        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:asset];// asset is an array

        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Finished Delete asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"deleted");
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.